# Check field length using awk

Tags: awk, field

I have a file of 3 fields:

```
123710337783,351898014413150,123028040249634
123710337785,352934028758390,123028040109275
```

I need to check that the fields meet the following lengths:

```
Field 1 = 12
Field 2 = 15 or 16
Field 3 = 15
```

I get an error when running this:

```
awk -F, '{if(length($2) == 15 ) || length($2) == 16) && length($1) == 12 && length($3)) == 15) print  }'
```

Please assist.

Bernie

Answer (score 25, accepted):

All your brackets are mismatched. An 'if' expression must be contained within brackets, i.e.,

```
if (X == 45) ...
if ((X == 45) || (Y == 23)) ...
```

you don't have this, and you've got more closing brackets than opening brackets - so the balance is off as well; if we count the brackets (increment for open, decrement for close), we end up with a total of -3 instead of 0, so closing three more brackets than we have open:

```
            1      2  1       0          1  0     -1          0 -1                0 -1 -2     -3
awk -F, '{if(length($2) == 15 ) || length($2) == 16) && length($1) == 12 && length($3)  ) == 15) print  }'
```

So, try this instead which rebalances everything:

```
awk -F, '{ if (((length($2) == 15 ) || length($2) == 16) && (length($1) == 12 && length($3) == 15)) print }'
```

Answer (score 11):

If all you're going to do is print, then put your expression as the default condition:

```
awk -F, 'length($1)==12 && (length($2)==15 || length($2)==16) && length($3)==15'
```

If you're trying to filter out lines in your input file that don't meet this criteria:

```
awk -F, '
    length($1)!=12 || length($2)<15 || length($2)>16 || length($3)!=15) {next}
    # do other stuff...
'
```

Answer (score 6):

You have mismatched/unbalanced parenthesis in conditional. Try:

```
{ if ((length($2) == 15 || length($2) == 16) && length($1) == 12 && length($3) == 15) print; }
```